# Generalised Eigenvectors | Correct way to Approach

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory, generalized-eigenvector

I have a matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$ I want to find out the generalised Eigenvectors. The Eigen values corresponding to the characteristic equation is $\lambda = 2$ and the Eigenvector correspondig to the eigenvalue is found to be $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

So how to calculate the generalised Eigen vector for this matrix.

---

What I did is ,

I took $(A-\lambda\cdot I)^2 \nu = 0$.

then solving the $(A-\lambda I)^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & 1 \\ -1 & 3-\lambda \end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda^2-2\lambda & 4 - 2\lambda \\ 2\lambda-4 & \lambda^2 - 6\lambda+8 \end{bmatrix}$

At this point I don't know whether I am doing the things correct . as finding the determinant will take this to $\lambda^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lambda=2$ has algebraic multiplicity equal to 2, the Jordan form is

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

then by $P=[v_1\,v_2]$

$$P^{-1}AP=J \implies AP=PJ$$

that is

- $Av_1=2v_1$ (already found)
- $Av_2=v_1+2v_2 \implies (A-2I)v_2=v_1$

Comment: I am sorry , but I didn't understand it . So no need to find , $(A-\lambda I)^2$ to find the generalised Eigen vectors.?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use Jordan forms here, I mean it works but there are simpler ways.

Comment: In your solutions, we know J, we know a, but P is partially unknown as we only know $v_1$, then how are you finding the $v_2$.

Comment: @Lawliet From the last system $(A-2I)v_2=v_1$.

Comment: Then what is the answer , I mean the generalised Eigen vector .?

Comment: @Lawliet You need to solve $$ \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1\end{bmatrix}$, I got these 2 among these which one to choose.?

Comment: @Lawliet Yes indeed any $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1\end{bmatrix}+t\cdot v_1$ works

Comment: so in general , $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x} = v_1$ is to be solved. If I have another set of repeated $\lambda \rightarrow (A-\lambda I)\vec{x} = v_2$ . No need to take$ (A-\lambda I)^2 $and solve.

Comment: @Lawliet When we can guess Jordan form, this is a way to proceed. User o's 1234 is suggesting another way, maybe preferable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda & 4-2\lambda \\
    2\lambda-4 & \lambda^2-6\lambda+8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, you can pick any eigenvector you want, so long as it does not satisfy $(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: How to find such a vector .?

Comment: Because the vector multiplied by the zero vector need be zero, you can pick basically any vector you want, so long as it is linearly independent from the vector you already chose.

Comment: Ok, can you just elaborate your answer with one of such vector as an example .?

Comment: How about $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$